# Hibernate 4: ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter exception

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to setup Hibernate 4 in a Maven project.
It doesn't work and it's driving me mad.

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/exception/ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter
```

These are the dependencies declared in the pom.xml file:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.dialect</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is my Hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:test.db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is the "crashy" code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I have only a test model, called "User", and is decorated with Hibernate annotations.

Can you help me with this? Cheers.

UPDATE: Stack trace

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failedjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/hibernate/exception/ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.matteopacini.RestaurantManager.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:27)
at com.matteopacini.RestaurantManager.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/exception/ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at  org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor    (StrategySelectorImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:78)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at com.matteopacini.RestaurantManager.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:21)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.exception.ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

Comment: What's the stack trace? Are you sure sqlite-dialect, which I haven't found on Maven central, is compatible with the recent Hibernate 4.3.1? The not found class is in org.hibernate.exception.spi in Hibernate 4, but was in org.hibernate.exception in Hibernate 3.6.

Comment: I posted the stack trace. sqlite-dialect repo: https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect. I don't know if it's compatibile, but it's the only one up-to-date.

Comment: You're missing a jar in the classpath or have 2 different versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialect you're using is not compatible with Hibernate 4. See https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java: it uses `org.hibernate.exception.ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter`, which has been moved to `org.hibernate.exception.spi.ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter` in Hibernate 4.

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me mad :D

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate 4.X the class `ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter` was moved from the package `org.hibernate.exception` to `org.hibernate.exception.spi` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/exception/spi/ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter.html)). The error message states that `org/hibernate/exception/ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter` was not found.

This means that you have at least one library in your runtime classpath that requests the old 3.X Hibernate class. You should check the dependenies using the Maven [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) or Eclipse.